# Setting transparent background in PHP or CSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress, sidebar

I'm using a Wordpress plugin in sidebar that forces me to select a background color (currently #ffffff) and I'm trying to override that option to achieve transparency. I am not able to simply leave that field blank in my Widget options. I have tried to modify via CSS with no luck. I believe the relevant code is below:

```
?>
            <li style="background-color: <?php echo $bg_color; ?>" class="<?php echo $icon_filename; ?>"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $$icon_url; ?>"><?php echo $icon_filename; ?></a></li>
            <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the opacity using `rgba()`

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
```

It's not widely supported because it is a CSS3 property, so you can set `background-color` or use `opacity` instead, but if you are using `opacity` it will also make the child element opaque, but there are many hacks where you can use `opacity` and prevent child elements from becoming opaque too

If you don't need the background at all simply use `background: none;`

[image: Demo]

Comment: Here ofcourse `<li style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);"`

Comment: I see. Made that change but it didn't eliminate background color entirely, and as you predicted it affected other elements.

Comment: @Niramaya you don't want the background color at all than simply use `background: none;`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much.. My other challenge (if I may) has to do w/ photostream widget at bottom of sidebar. Once I set the actual sidebar's background to transparent, it changed the way that widget behaves. Whereas before hovering on an image would bring it into focus, it now just makes it darker upon hover. Here's how the widget should behave: http://demo.brankic.net/bigbangwp/2012/07/divinum-dare-humanum-accipere/

Comment: @Niramaya Ok I saw the widget on the other website so what you exactly want?

Comment: Re: photo widget, I'm trying to maintain its "proper" behavior on a transparent widget background. "Whereas before hovering on an image would bring it into focus, it now just makes it darker upon hover."

Comment: Hmm.. nothing displays in blocks in Result pane so not sure.

Comment: @Niramaya ya because I've just made containers, am not understanding how you actually want

Comment: ok, let me try again: 1. On widget demo site {the 6 images display at low opacity, hovering over them brings them to focus. 2. On my site w/ transparent sidebar {images display at low opacity, hovering over merely makes them darker instead of focused}

Comment: @Niramaya remove `!important` from `.photostream img {opacity: 0.7;}` and don't use `!important` unnecessary, it will invite more trouble

Comment: and... that worked ;) Thanks a million. that "important" was in there when i downloaded widget. I'm learning. Happy holidays! I'd double-accept if I could ;) Cheers! R

Comment: @Niramaya hehe it's fyn ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the opacity/transparency with CSS by using "opacity:0.0;".

Change your code to something like this:

```
<li style="background-color: <?php echo $bg_color; ?> opacity:0.0;" class="<?php echo $icon_filename; ?>"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $$icon_url; ?>"><?php echo $icon_filename; ?></a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to achieve desire result w/ just setting background to "none."

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS background opacity/transparency property

```
body { background-color: trasparent }
```

or

```
body { opacity: 0.1 }
```